# Why did Sass fell down on HighSierra?

Tags: macos, sass, rubygems

Updated macOS to HighSierra, tried to launch scss watcher and got this:

> -bash: /usr/local/bin/sass: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby:
>   bad interpreter: No such file or directory

When I am trying to reinstall with

> sudo gem install sass

it I see this error:

> Building native extensions.  This could take a while... ERROR:  Error
>   installing sass:  ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
> current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.18/ext/ffi_c
> ```
>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby -r
>   ./siteconf20171012-1933-1pk37g.rb extconf.rb mkmf.rb can't find header
>   files for ruby at
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h
>
> extconf failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.18 for inspection. Results
>   logged to
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-17/2.3.0/ffi-1.9.18/gem_make.out

How may I solve it?

Comment: I've got the same issue - did you find a fix?

Comment: @Sam Nope. forced to use Gulp instead for Scss compiler

Answer (score 3):

I followed this solution from iamcubcs (https://github.com/oklai/koala/issues/679)

1. Open Terminal
2. Install Homebrew:   `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`
3. Do not close Terminal, open Mac Appstore and check Update, install all XCode Command Line Tools updates OR in my case, XCode Command Line Tools started install automaticly throught Terminal right after step 2.
4. Back to Terminal
5. Install Ruby:   `brew install rbenv ruby-build`
6. Install SASS gem:   `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin sass`

This worked for me

Comment: Fixes AWOL SCSS after macOS Catilina upgrade as well.